# branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions handler getting triggered on app exit

Tags: branch.io

By setting breakpoints, i noticed that the handler was getting called when the app is exiting.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, why would branch want to do this?

```
// This is in app delegate
branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController: true, deepLinkHandler: { params, error in
      // breakpoint
      if error == nil {
        self.handleDeepLink(params)
      }
      else {
        error?.showInToast()
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch here: this is not expected behavior from our SDK. Are you overriding any of the other app lifecycle methods (e.g., `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationWillResignActive`)?

Comment: hi akex, not that i know! let me put some breakpoints and get back to you. it is very sporadic.